# How to declare an empty dictionary of empty dictionaries in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

To declare an empty dictionary, I do:

```
mydict = dict()
```

To declare an empty dictionary of empty dictionaries, I can do also:

```
mydictofdict = dict()
```

Then add dictionaries when needed:

```
mydict1 = dict()
mydictofdict.update({1:mydict1})
```

and elements in them when desired:

```
mydictofdict[1].update({'mykey1':'myval1'})
```

Is it pythonic? Is there a better way to perform it?

Comment: Why not `mydictofdict[1] = mydict1` and `mydictofdict[1]['mykey1'] = 'myval1'`? If you intend to update an arbitrary number of values then that is exactly what `update()` was designed to do in the first place.

Comment: Are your dicts static? Why don't you just declare ``mydictofdict = {1: {}}``? If they are dynamic, why not use ``mydictofdict[1] = mydict1``?

Comment: Great, first level is static and second is dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for a nested dictionary, where you define an initial value of a dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict

#Use the initial value as a dictionary
dct = defaultdict(dict)

dct['a']['b'] = 'c'
dct['d']['e'] = 'f'

print(dct)
```

The output will be

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'a': {'b': 'c'}, 'd': {'e': 'f'}})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create empty dict with `{}`:

`d = {}`

You can create dict of dict (as values) the way like the first:

```
d = {
    1: {},
    2: {}
}
```

You can modify the dict's value by `[]`:

```
d = {1: 0}
d[1] = 1
d
```

> `{1: 1}`

The similar with dict in dict:

```
d = {
    1: {},
    2: {}
}
d[1][4] = 5
d
```

> `{1: {4: 5}, 2: {}}`

If you want to create a dict of dicts according to the list of keys, you can use dict comprehensions:

```
keys = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = {key: {} for key in keys}
d
```

> `{1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, 4: {}, 5: {}}`